# How is this solution for dining philosophers problem (dpp) working? Mutex and semaphores

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, dining-philosopher

I am trying to solve the ***dining philosophers problem*** (*the problem:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) and I found the solution with code below. Solution uses semaphores and one mutex. I implemented busy waiting simple semaphores myself, cause C++ does not provide semaphores. I can't understand what's the purpose of mutex locking in `take_forks` and `put_forks` functions.

I tried to find the answer to my question, but I couldn't. So I am asking in stackoverflow.

#### My questions are:

1. What's the purpose of mutex locking in `take_forks` and `put_forks` functions? (What can cause for race condition to occur?)
2. What's the name of this solution? Is this the arbitration solution?

### Here's my code

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

#define N 5
#define THINKING 0
#define HUNGRY 1
#define EATING 2

typedef int sem_t;
void sem_up(sem_t* semaphore) {
    (*semaphore)++;
}
void sem_down(sem_t* semaphore) {
    while (*semaphore == 0) {}
    (*semaphore)--;
}

std::mutex mutualExclusion;
char philosopherState[N] = {THINKING};
sem_t philosopherSemaphore[N] = { 0 };

void test(short i) {
    if (philosopherState[i] == HUNGRY && philosopherState[(i + 1) % N] != EATING && philosopherState[(i + N - 1) % N] != EATING) {
        philosopherState[i] = EATING;
        sem_up(&philosopherSemaphore[i]);
    }
}

void think(short p) {
    //some code
}
void eat() {
        //some code
}

void take_forks(short i) {
    ::mutualExclusion.lock();
    philosopherState[i] = HUNGRY;
    test(i);
    ::mutualExclusion.unlock();
    sem_down(&philosopherSemaphore[i]);
}
void put_forks(short i) {
    ::mutualExclusion.lock();
    philosopherState[i] = THINKING;
    test((i + 1) % N);
    test((i + N - 1) % N);
    ::mutualExclusion.unlock();
}

void philosopher(short i) {
    while (1) {
        think();
        take_forks(i);
        eat();
        put_forks(i);
    }
}
```

I expected that mutex locking must be in `test` function, because that's the only cause for race condition that I found.

#### Any answers and suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You `semaphore` behavior is not defined because you read the variable outside of a lock or some other synchronization primitive. So at some point, the value might become incorrect. This could be even worst if you turn on compiler optimization as the compiler might assume that `semaphore` is not modified by another thread.

Comment: @Phil1970 So, can I fix that by making a class and adding  mutex lock to that class and lock-unlock mutex when doing semaphore up and down?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith for more information on atomic increment and decrement in standard C++. A mutex have more overhead than an atomic operation. A good reading for anyone that want to write multithreaded code in C++ is **C++ Concurrency In Action** by **Anthony Williams**.

Comment: @Phil1970 Ok, i will check that and i'll edit the code of the question corresponding.

Comment: The problem with non atomic operation could be as following. Both thread read the value from memory into a register, both increment their value in a register and both write the value back from the register to the memory. Thus the number would have been incremented by 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yes, that's a race condition! I tried to solve that problem with mutex and I was getting a "mutex destroyed while busy error". I asked about that error and a user noted that I am using global mutex which is being destroyed when main() function returns. You can check that question from my profile, later I will place a link under this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **I found answer to my question.**

This solution is introduced by A. Tanenbaum and is one of several solutions that are called arbitration. By this approach it is guaranteed that a philosopher can only pick up ***either forks or none*** by introducing an ***arbitrator, e.g., a waiter***.In order to pick up the forks, a philosopher must ask permission of the waiter. The waiter gives permission to only one philosopher at a time until he has picked up both his forks. The waiter can be implemented as a mutex. Thus, the operation of checking and updating the array is atomic and exclusive access to forks is guaranteed. (That's the purpose of mutex)

---

### Several references

- [https://www.cs.grinnell.edu/~weinman/courses/CSC213/2012F/labs/philosophers.html](https://www.cs.grinnell.edu/%7Eweinman/courses/CSC213/2012F/labs/philosophers.html)
- https://itsphbytes.wordpress.com/2016/09/26/dining-philosophers-problem/
- https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs241/fa2010/ppt/25-ClassicSynch.pdf